# Displaying a dialog from within a Polymer component

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, polymer, web-component

I've a polymer component, from inside of one of its function I want to display a dialog to the user.
I tried with [dialog-paper](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-dialog.html) as follows:

```
<template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/the-graph-dark.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/the-graph-light.css">
  <div id="svgcontainer"></div>
  <paper-dialog heading="Title for dialog" id="dialog">
    <p>Lorem ipsum ....</p>
    <p>Id qui scripta ...</p>
    <paper-button label="More Info..." dismissive></paper-button>
    <paper-button label="Decline" affirmative></paper-button>
    <paper-button label="Accept" affirmative autofocus></paper-button>
  </paper-dialog>
</template>
...
eventHandler: function(event) {
  this.$.dialog.toggle();
  console.log(event);
},
```

When I try to toggle the dialog when the eventHandler is invoked nothing is shown and I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

What is the appropriate way to display a dialog from within a component?

Comment: try this.$.dialog.shadowRoot.toggle();

Comment: this.$.dialog.shadowRoot gives `null`!

Comment: ahh I know what it is! "this" refers to "event" from the function and not the template. Try make a variable like: that: this, and use "that" instead. Also put the "eventHandler" inside the "ready" function...

Comment: this on console (with a breakpoint inside the eventHandler()) gives the polymer object and not the event

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this**

```
Polymer({
  that: this,
  ready: function(){
      addEventListener('on-blabla-event', function(event){
        that.$.dialog.toggle();
        console.log(event);
      });
    }
});
```